# Keeping the context when archiving in Emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I generally use org-mode to keep track of TODOs. I have files like:

```
* Misc.
** TODO Task 1
** TODO Task 2
* Project 1
** TODO Task 1
** TODO Task 2
```

While archiving whole subtrees like `Project 1` work as intended, I am not to able to move `Task 1` in `Misc.` such that the archive file looks like this (ignoring PROPERTIES in this example):

```
* Misc
** DONE Task 1
```

In other words, I want to keep all sections a task belongs to. Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: I've been using [this code](https://gist.github.com/edgimar/072d99d8650abe81a9fe7c8687c0c993) for a while, and it works very well (updated for Emacs 26), moving a complete path + subtree to the archive heading.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You likely want to set the `:ARCHIVE:` property on the parent headlines.

It allows you for headline specific `org-archive-location` settings. (See the [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Moving-subtrees.html#Moving-subtrees))

For example if your archive file is set as `%s_archive` you would want your original file to look like this

```
* Misc.
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ARCHIVE:  %s_archive::* Misc
  :END:
** TODO Task 1
** TODO Task 2
* Project 1
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ARCHIVE:  %s_archive::* Project 1
  :END:
** TODO Task 1
** TODO Task 2
```

This would sent any subtrees in `* Misc` to a `* Misc` headline in the archive file, and would do the equivalent for the subtrees in `Project 1` (unless you archive the whole tree in one shot).  Archiving the parent tree after the subtrees appears to add it as an additional subheading under the destination.  It does not support multiple levels, so you'd have to set up your archive file headlines ahead of time to ensure it outputs the way you desire if you need a complex setup of that sort.

You can also use this property to archive specific trees to separate files (for export/publication/sharing purposes).

Comment: This is a very nice and clean solution. Works as intended. My setup is simple enough so I guess won't have problems with the lacking support of multiple levels. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

```
;; org-archive-subtree-hierarchical.el
;; modified from https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-08/msg00109.html

;; In orgmode
;; * A
;; ** AA
;; *** AAA
;; ** AB
;; *** ABA
;; Archiving AA will remove the subtree from the original file and create
;; it like that in archive target:

;; * AA
;; ** AAA

;; And this give you
;; * A
;; ** AA
;; *** AAA


(require 'org-archive)

(defun org-archive-subtree-hierarchical--line-content-as-string ()
  "Returns the content of the current line as a string"
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-line)
    (buffer-substring-no-properties
     (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))))

(defun org-archive-subtree-hierarchical--org-child-list ()
  "This function returns all children of a heading as a list. "
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    ;; this only works with org-version > 8.0, since in previous
    ;; org-mode versions the function (org-outline-level) returns
    ;; gargabe when the point is not on a heading.
    (if (= (org-outline-level) 0)
        (outline-next-visible-heading 1)
      (org-goto-first-child))
    (let ((child-list (list (org-archive-subtree-hierarchical--line-content-as-string))))
      (while (org-goto-sibling)
        (setq child-list (cons (org-archive-subtree-hierarchical--line-content-as-string) child-list)))
      child-list)))

(defun org-archive-subtree-hierarchical--org-struct-subtree ()
  "This function returns the tree structure in which a subtree
belongs as a list."
  (interactive)
  (let ((archive-tree nil))
    (save-excursion
      (while (org-up-heading-safe)
        (let ((heading
               (buffer-substring-no-properties
                (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))))
          (if (eq archive-tree nil)
              (setq archive-tree (list heading))
            (setq archive-tree (cons heading archive-tree))))))
    archive-tree))

(defun org-archive-subtree-hierarchical ()
  "This function archives a subtree hierarchical"
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-tree (org-archive-subtree-hierarchical--org-struct-subtree))
        (this-buffer (current-buffer))
        (file (abbreviate-file-name
               (or (buffer-file-name (buffer-base-buffer))
                   (error "No file associated to buffer")))))
    (save-excursion
      (setq location (org-get-local-archive-location)
            afile (org-extract-archive-file location)
            heading (org-extract-archive-heading location)
            infile-p (equal file (abbreviate-file-name (or afile ""))))
      (unless afile
        (error "Invalid `org-archive-location'"))
      (if (> (length afile) 0)
          (setq newfile-p (not (file-exists-p afile))
                visiting (find-buffer-visiting afile)
                buffer (or visiting (find-file-noselect afile)))
        (setq buffer (current-buffer)))
      (unless buffer
        (error "Cannot access file \"%s\"" afile))
      (org-cut-subtree)
      (set-buffer buffer)
      (org-mode)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (not (equal org-tree nil))
        (let ((child-list (org-archive-subtree-hierarchical--org-child-list)))
          (if (member (car org-tree) child-list)
              (progn
                (search-forward (car org-tree) nil t)
                (setq org-tree (cdr org-tree)))
            (progn
              (goto-char (point-max))
              (newline)
              (org-insert-struct org-tree)
              (setq org-tree nil)))))
      (newline)
      (org-yank)
      (when (not (eq this-buffer buffer))
        (save-buffer))
      (message "Subtree archived %s"
               (concat "in file: " (abbreviate-file-name afile))))))

(defun org-insert-struct (struct)
  "TODO"
  (interactive)
  (when struct
    (insert (car struct))
    (newline)
    (org-insert-struct (cdr struct))))

(defun org-archive-subtree ()
  (org-archive-subtree-hierarchical)
  )
```

This hack just act like refile to your archive file with whole same parent struct，no archive `:PROPERTIES:` here.

Also as a gist here: https://gist.github.com/CodeFalling/87b116291aa87fde72cb

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!

Comment: Loved it. Combines nicely with a key in the agenda:
(define-key org-agenda-mode-map "z" 'org-agenda-archive)

Comment: Dang. This seems to be refiling the subtree to the end of the archive file, instead of the correct subtree higher in the archive file. It has been a couple of years since it's published. Have to debug it sometime.

Comment: Here is updated version for use with new Org-mode (if you are getting `Symbol's function definition is void: org-archive-subtree-hierarchical`) https://gist.github.com/kepi/2f4acc3cc93403c75fbba5684c5d852d

Answer (score 6):

I don't think `org-mode` has support for directly mirroring the current context inside your archive file.

There is a relevant variable, `org-archive-location` which can be used to specify a single heading to place your archived item, but multiple levels inside the tree is not supported. On [this page](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-hacks.html) there are two advices for `org-archive-subtree` that may be good enough. I am replicating the first one here in case the site goes away:

```lisp
(defadvice org-archive-subtree (around my-org-archive-subtree activate)
  (let ((org-archive-location
         (if (save-excursion (org-back-to-heading)
                             (> (org-outline-level) 1))
             (concat (car (split-string org-archive-location "::"))
                     "::* "
                     (car (org-get-outline-path)))
           org-archive-location)))
    ad-do-it))
```

The second, and more complicated one also preserves tags found on the top level headings.

On last thing that may come in handy is the custom variable `org-archive-save-context-info`. If this list contains the symbol `'olpath`, the archived entry will contain `:ARCHIVE_OLPATH:` property, which is set to the outline path of the archived entry (e.g. `Projects/Misc`. Maybe you can do some post processing on the `org-archive-subtree` and relocate the archived entry to its original outline path using this.